# how to call a soap webservice in IBM websphere portal / WCM?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, websphere-portal

Im trying to call SOAP webservice in IBM Websphere portal 8.5 / WCM using a HTML Javascript call from a simple page. 
It retun the ERROR

```
SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for ************ required Cross Origin Resource 
Sharing (CORS).

SEC7119: XMLHttpRequest for http://********** required CORS preflight.

SEC7120: Origin http://******* not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.
File: Status

SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.
```

Is there any Solution to it?

Or any other way to call webservice from IBM WPS WCM?

Comment: Where are you calling the webservice from? a portlet? wcm content?  Also is this specific to IE or does it happen in all browsers?

Comment: I am Calling it from WCM content as HTML javascript. code. this is specific to IE only other browser's does not return anything.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be a known issue with IE by the looks of the google search: https://www.google.com/search?q=SCRIPT7002&oq=SCRIPT7002&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j0l4.447j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8.  For calling external services the recommendation in Portal is to use the AJAX Proxy or the Outbound HTTP Connection Env like I noted on my answer.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To make cross site calls you should use either the AJAX Proxy or Outbound HTTP Connection Env in WebSphere Portal.  Take a look at the documentation here: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHRKX_8.5.0/mp/dev-portlet/outbound_http.html